# Angular js owl slider data filtering issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, owl-carousel

I have to create owl slider with ng-repeat to make slides.I am facing a problem when,I filter the data with dropdown, the values in the slide is updated but the slider is not working and break the UI.I have created a codepen for this issue.`

```
    <div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <select ng-change="refreshData(selectedItem)" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="opt for opt in filterValues" >
               <option value="" selected="selected">Select the filter</option>
            </select>
            <data-owl-carousel class="owl-carousel" data-options="{navigation: false, pagination: true, rewindNav : false,items:4,pagination : true, paginationNumbers: false}">
               <div owl-carousel-item="" ng-repeat="item in  filterData" class="items" data-owl-carousel>
                  <img src="{{item.src}}"/>
                  <h4 class="text-center">{{item.category}}</h4>
               </div>
            </data-owl-carousel>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the url of [Codepen](http://codepen.io/satnam348/pen/XdNRyZ) for reference

Comment: does my answer solve the problem? If so, then consider marking it a "accepted" and if not - please comment on it and explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: sorry for late reply . your answer solve the problem, thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that owlCarousel wraps the orignal items into additional divs, the HTML looks like this:

```
<data-owl-carousel class="owl-carousel owl-theme" data-options="...">
      <!-- ngRepeat: item in  filterData -->
      <div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
          <div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 4320px; left: 0px; display: block;">
              <div class="owl-item" style="width: 240px;">
                  <div owl-carousel-item="" ng-repeat="item in  filterData" class="items ng-scope" data-owl-carousel="">
                    <img src="http://compareindia.ibnlive.com/media/gallery/images/2012/jul/beam_1_031058257405.jpg">
                    <h4 class="text-center ng-binding">samsung</h4>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="owl-item" style="width: 240px;">
                  <div owl-carousel-item="" ng-repeat="item in  filterData" class="items ng-scope" data-owl-carousel="">
                    <img src="http://www.india777.com/company_prof/11-07-2012-05-32-58-samsung-mobile-GT-S6802.jpg">
                    <h4 class="text-center ng-binding">samsung</h4>
                  </div>
              </div>
              ...
```

You can see that original divs with `.owl-carousel-item` class are wrapped into additional `.owl-item` divs.

Once you filter the data, angular removes the ng-repeated divs and inserts new, but it knows nothing about wrappers, so the HTML becomes this:

```
<data-owl-carousel class="owl-carousel owl-theme" data-options="...">
    <!-- ngRepeat: item in  filterData -->
    <div owl-carousel-item="" ng-repeat="item in  filterData" class="items ng-scope" data-owl-carousel="">
        <img src="http://compareindia.ibnlive.com/media/gallery/images/2012/jul/beam_1_031058257405.jpg">
        <h4 class="text-center ng-binding">samsung</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
        <div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 5706px; left: 0px; display: block; transition: all 0ms ease; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
            <div class="owl-item" style="width: 317px;"></div>
            <div class="owl-item" style="width: 317px;"></div>
            ...
```

Here at the top there is a new (filtered) data and then the empty owlCarousel's wrappers.

The solution (code is below) is to destroy / recreate the owlCarousel when the data is filtered.
Other solutions can be to modify the owlCarousel code to not use the wrapper divs or to switch to some other, more angular-friendly carousel.

Anyway, here is the working code:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope,$filter,$timeout) {
  //$scope.items2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
  $scope.carouselData =[
{"category":"samsung","src":"http://compareindia.ibnlive.com/media/gallery/images/2012/jul/beam_1_031058257405.jpg"},
{"category":"samsung","src":"http://www.india777.com/company_prof/11-07-2012-05-32-58-samsung-mobile-GT-S6802.jpg"},
{"category":"apple","src":"http://androidos.in/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Galaxy-S-II-T_Mobile.jpg"},
{"category":"apple","src":"http://www.pakmobileprice.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Samsung-Galaxy-S6-EDGE.jpg"},

{"category":"apple","src":"http://www.pakmobileprice.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Samsung-Galaxy-S6-EDGE.jpg"},

{"category":"apple","src":"http://www.pakmobileprice.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Samsung-Galaxy-S6-EDGE.jpg"},

{"category":"apple","src":"http://www.pakmobileprice.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Samsung-Galaxy-S6-EDGE.jpg"},

{"category":"samsung","src":"http://compareindia.ibnlive.com/media/gallery/images/2012/jul/beam_1_031058257405.jpg"},
{"category":"samsung","src":"http://www.india777.com/company_prof/11-07-2012-05-32-58-samsung-mobile-GT-S6802.jpg"}

];
 $scope.filterValues = ['samsung','apple'];

$scope.refreshData = function(val){
    $scope.filterData = [];
    // notify the carousel about data change
    $rootScope.$broadcast('owlCarousel.changeStart');
    $timeout(function(){
        if (!val) val = '';
        $scope.filterData = $filter('filter')($scope.carouselData, {category: val});
        console.log($scope.filterData);
        // notify the carousel that data is changed
        $rootScope.$broadcast('owlCarousel.changeEnd');
    });  
}
$scope.refreshData('');
}).directive("owlCarousel", function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: false,
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.initCarousel = function(element) {
              // provide any default options you want
                var defaultOptions = {
                };
                var customOptions = scope.$eval($(element).attr('data-options'));
                // combine the two options objects
                for(var key in customOptions) {
                    defaultOptions[key] = customOptions[key];
                }
                // init carousel
                $(element).owlCarousel(defaultOptions);
              
                // Event to remove the carousel on data change start
                scope.$on('owlCarousel.changeStart', function(data) {
                    console.log('owlCarousel.destroy');
                    var data = $(element).data('owlCarousel');
                    if (data) data.destroy();                    
                });
                // Event to create the carousel back when data change is completed
                scope.$on('owlCarousel.changeEnd', function(data) {
                    $timeout(function() {
                      console.log('owlCarousel.create ');
                      $(element).owlCarousel(defaultOptions);
                    });  
                });
            };
            
        }
    };
})
.directive('owlCarouselItem', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: false,
        link: function(scope, element) {
          // wait for the last item in the ng-repeat then call init
            if(scope.$last) {
                scope.initCarousel(element.parent());
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

```css
.items img
{
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.transitions.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.15"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.3" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">


<select ng-change="refreshData(selectedItem)" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="opt for opt in filterValues" >
     <option value="" selected="selected">Select the filter</option>
                                      
      </select>
      

    <data-owl-carousel class="owl-carousel" data-options="{navigation: false, pagination: true, rewindNav : false,items:4,pagination : true, paginationNumbers: false}">
      <div owl-carousel-item="" ng-repeat="item in  filterData" class="items" data-owl-carousel>
        <img src="{{item.src}}"/>
         <h4 class="text-center">{{item.category}}</h4>
            </div>
    </data-owl-carousel>
</div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: You could also destroy the carousel using:

``$(element).owlCarousel('destroy');``